# R: Make part of cell bold in shiny table output

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the R shiny app and creating a table using renderTable and tableOutput. Is it possible to make one part of a cells contents bold whilst keeping the rest of it normal text.

E.g. one entry in a particular cell could be:

**5.3%** ~ 1% ~ 7

I tried hardcoding ** around the appropriate figure but it just outputted the asterisk.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `<strong></strong>` HTML tag in your table if you want some bold text, here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
data<-data.frame(a=c("<strong>a</strong>","b"),val=c(1,2))

runApp(list(
        ui = basicPage(
                tableOutput('mytable')
        ),
        server = function(input, output) {
                output$mytable = renderTable({
                        data
                },sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
        }
))
```

You need to change the `sanitize.text.function` to identity in order for the tags to be interpreted.

As an alternative, you can also use [Datatables](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html) to render your table. You can also use the `<strong>` tag, but make sure you set the `escape` option to false in the `renderDataTable` part.